# xargs does not seem to separate parameters

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to use `xargs` to set secrets in github using the `gh` CLI.

Given I have an .env file with the following entries

```
SECRET1=djfjgdfkjg
SECRET2=jbnfdgjn
SECRET3=A line of text
```

And the `sed` command `sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)=(.*)$/\1 -b "\2"/g' ./.env` produces the following output:

```
SECRET1 -b "djfjgdfkjg"
SECRET2 -b "jbnfdgjn"
SECRET3 -b "A line of text"
```

I am unsure as to why the command:

`sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)=(.*)$/\1 -b "\2"/g' test.env | xargs -I {} gh secret set {}`

fails for each secret with the message `secret name can only contain letters, numbers, and _`

Manually running `gh secret set SECRET1 -b "djfjgdfkjg"` works without an error.

I'm guessing that the issue is that the first arg (secret name) is being passed the value `SECRET1 -b "djfjgdfkjg"` rather than just `SECRET1` but I'm unsure how I can fix this?

Comment: Usually, when a command is run correctly from the command line, but not from a script, the problem could come from losing the quotes. Since we can't reproduce your problem, for not having access to the command `secret`, we only can guess that you could add a backslash (or maybe two) before the quotes: `sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z0-9_]*)=(.*)$/\1 -b \\"\2\\"/g' ./.env`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit more digging I discovered that the problem is the use of `-I` and that:

```
sed -rn 's/^[[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*)=(.*)$/\1 -b "\2"/p' .env | xargs -n 3 gh secret set
```

resolves the problem.